# Unable to align these buttons to the left unless I add a paragraph

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

So I have a component

```
const Skills = () => {
    return (
        <div className="w-full p-2 flex items-center  py-16 bg-blue-50">
            <div className="max-w-[1240px] m-auto">
                <div className="">
                    <button className="shadow-xl bg-gradient-to-r from-[#5651e5] to-[#709dff] text-white rounded-md p-2 mx-2">Skills</button>
                    <button className="shadow-xl bg-gradient-to-r from-[#5651e5] to-[#709dff] text-white rounded-md p-2 mx-2">Hobbies</button>
                    

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image: This is what it looks like(It's the one with the light blue background)]
And I want to center it so that it matches my upper component but I have been unable to do this but the thing is if I add a paragraph with enough text so that it wraps then it works

```
const Skills = () => {
    return (
        <div className="w-full p-2 flex items-center  py-16 bg-blue-50">
            <div className="max-w-[1240px] m-auto">
                <div className="">
                    <button className="shadow-xl bg-gradient-to-r from-[#5651e5] to-[#709dff] text-white rounded-md p-2 mx-2">Skills</button>
                    <button className="shadow-xl bg-gradient-to-r from-[#5651e5] to-[#709dff] text-white rounded-md p-2 mx-2">Hobbies</button>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorum impedit, ex architecto sunt deleniti dolor provident nihil rerum, pariatur libero, non laboriosam! Repellendus quod porro aut repudiandae iusto aliquid?</p>
                    

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image: Here]
Does anyone know how I could possibly fix this without having a paragraph I don't want in here?

Comment: Not sure if you want to center it or having it aligned on the left? also the markup you have won't work with the paragraph anyways. It will push the elements out because the container of the button is not flex nor grid. Can you clarify? The buttons should be on the center or on the left?

Answer (score 0):

So first thing, why adding the paragraph push the items to the left? because the container of the button is not a flex container and has no alignment applied to it.

But to achieve what you want you need first to remove the this "m-auto" it will push items to the center anyways if you use that.

then add "justify-start" to the main container.

[Here is a sample](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2uOUXr8KUT).

Comment: Yeah this is weird because I tried something similar and it didn't work. And now after pasting your code and simply replacing it with mine it still doesn't work weirdly..

Comment: Oh wait n this does work but it aligns it to the total left, I want to basically align it to the left within the 1240px container though so if it's m-auto then there's 620 pixels on the left and right, I basically want to push these two buttons 620 pixels to the left so they are aligned to the left of the container with max width.

Comment: Not sure I understand, maybe update your question because adding m-auto will not work with flex positioning, also you need to make the direct parent container a flex container as well if you want to align the items that way. So it is not clear if you want it just to be pushed to the left or if you want to have the button on the left of its container. because then you are talking about nested flex alignment.